# SQL SD: Identify the most recent common past opponent between two teams

Tags: sql, oracle

I need some help to write a rather complicated Oracle SQL query.

I have a table which contains a list of games played between two teams with the following columns:

1. `Game Date` (date)
2. `Home Team` (varchar2(26)),
3. `Opposition Team` (varchar2(26)),
4. `Score Difference` (number(38))

I have also created an index which is simply a unique ID for every single game (each row in the table) called  'Indexing'.

There are approximately 30 teams in the competition, and more than 5 thousand games which have been played.

For each match up (one per row), I would like to be able to identify a third team (called Shared Opponent) which is the most recent (in days) opponent that is shared by the Home Team and Opposition Team.  I would then like to calculate the score difference for both match-ups (Home Team v Shared Opponent and Opposing Team vs Shared opponent) of these historical matches on the same row as the details for the current match (between Home Team and Opposing team)

My attempt so far looks something like this

```
SELECT 
  A.GAME_DATE,
  A.GAME_NUMBER,
  A.INDEXING,
  A.HOME_TEAM,
  A.OPP_TEAM,
  B.OPP_TEAM AS SHARED_OPP,
  B.SCORE_DIFF AS OPP_SCORE_DIFF,
  C.SCORE_DIFF AS HOME_SCORE_DIFF,
  MIN((A.GAME_DATE - B.GAME_DATE)+ (A.GAME_DATE - C.GAME_DATE) + ABS(B.GAME_DATE - C.GAME_DATE)) AS TOTAL_DATE_DIFF

FROM
TEAM_SUMMARY_1 A
LEFT JOIN TEAM_SUMMARY_1 B ON A.OPP_TEAM = B.HOME_TEAM
LEFT JOIN TEAM_SUMMARY_1 C ON A.HOME_TEAM = C.HOME_TEAM
WHERE 
B.OPP_TEAM <> A.HOME_TEAM AND
A.OPP_TEAM <> C.OPP_TEAM AND
B.OPP_TEAM = C.OPP_TEAM AND
ABS(B.GAME_DATE - C.GAME_DATE) < 5 AND
A.GAME_DATE - B.GAME_DATE < 20 AND
A.GAME_DATE - B.GAME_DATE > 0 AND 
A.GAME_DATE - C.GAME_DATE < 20 AND
A.GAME_DATE - C.GAME_DATE > 0 
GROUP BY
  A.GAME_DATE,
  A.GAME_NUMBER,
  A.INDEXING,
  A.HOME_TEAM,
  A.OPP_TEAM,
  B.OPP_TEAM,
  B.SCORE_DIFF,
  C.SCORE_DIFF
ORDER BY
  A.GAME_DATE,
  A.HOME_TEAM,
  A.OPP_TEAM
```

This code does return what I'm after, in a way, however the MIN applied to the total date difference is not working.

I don't mind if I have to do this in multiple steps, but at the moment I can't seem to conceptualize the process in my head.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you add table structure, relations, sample data, expected output and your DBMS (sql server, mysql, oracle etc), and, ideally, a query you already tried

Comment: Thanks HoneyBadger, I've added as much as I could. Afraid this is my first time posting so wasn't sure of the requirements.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN TEAM_SUMMARY_1 B ON A.OPP_TEAM = B.HOME_TEAM` you are missing the case where `LEFT JOIN TEAM_SUMMARY_1 B ON B.OPP_TEAM = A.HOME_TEAM` (and the same for C ) Also, I don't think you need a *LEFT* join here; you only want matching teams. (But referring to B.xxx and C.xxx in the WHERE clause will effectively cause the left joins to act as plain joins)

Comment: For future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It seems to me that there could well be two most recent shared opponents.

Comment: Hi Joop. I am specifically avoiding the case where TEAM_SUMMARY_1 B ON B.OPP_TEAM = A.HOME_TEAM, because in the source data I have, each game is listed twice, once where it is a home game and once where it is an away game for the opposition.  I realize i didn't explain this in my description above, and the naming convention i have used here also suggests otherwise.  Apologies. I was aiming to simplify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this and apply it  the same idea to your table structure.

Table used, score can be positive or negative or 0 for a tie.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Game
(
 PlayDate DATETIME,
 HomeTeam INT,
 OpposingTeam INT,
 Score INT
)
```

Query used

```
WITH GAME AS
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY G1.PlayDate) I, * FROM dbo.Games G1
)
, SHARED AS
(
    SELECT 
    G.I, 
    G.HomeTeam, 
    G.OpposingTeam, 
    H.HomeTeam AS H, 
    H.OpposingTeam AS H2, 
    H.I AS HI, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY G.I ORDER BY H.I DESC) AS A
    FROM GAME G
    LEFT JOIN GAME H ON 
        (G.OpposingTeam = H.OpposingTeam OR G.OpposingTeam = H.HomeTeam) 
        AND G.HomeTeam <> H.HomeTeam 
        AND G.HomeTeam <> H.OpposingTeam
    WHERE G.I > H.I
)

SELECT G.*, H.HI 
FROM GAME G
LEFT JOIN SHARED H ON G.I = H.I
WHERE A = 1 OR A IS NULL
ORDER BY G.I
```

Basicly `G.I` id's any single game. `H.HI` is the matching game with a shared apponent. You can get whatever fields you want from the `SHARED` CTE like the score of the shared game, if the shared opponent was on the home or opposing team and so on. Some of it could be beutified a bit but it should work.

Games with no shared opponents come out where `H` is NULL

Test data

```
INSERT [dbo].[Games] ([PlayDate], [HomeTeam], [OpposingTeam], [Score]) VALUES (CAST(N'2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1, 2, 5)
INSERT [dbo].[Games] ([PlayDate], [HomeTeam], [OpposingTeam], [Score]) VALUES (CAST(N'2015-01-04 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1, 2, 10)
INSERT [dbo].[Games] ([PlayDate], [HomeTeam], [OpposingTeam], [Score]) VALUES (CAST(N'2015-01-10 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1, 2, -3)
INSERT [dbo].[Games] ([PlayDate], [HomeTeam], [OpposingTeam], [Score]) VALUES (CAST(N'2015-01-07 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 3, 2, -5)
INSERT [dbo].[Games] ([PlayDate], [HomeTeam], [OpposingTeam], [Score]) VALUES (CAST(N'2015-01-13 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2, 3, -8)
INSERT [dbo].[Games] ([PlayDate], [HomeTeam], [OpposingTeam], [Score]) VALUES (CAST(N'2015-01-04 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2, 1, -8)
INSERT [dbo].[Games] ([PlayDate], [HomeTeam], [OpposingTeam], [Score]) VALUES (CAST(N'2015-01-15 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 3, 1, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[Games] ([PlayDate], [HomeTeam], [OpposingTeam], [Score]) VALUES (CAST(N'2015-01-20 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 3, 2, 9)
INSERT [dbo].[Games] ([PlayDate], [HomeTeam], [OpposingTeam], [Score]) VALUES (CAST(N'2015-01-24 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1, 3, -15)
```

Answer (score 0):

The date-logic is a bit different, but is avoids substraction of dates:

```
        -- CTE to exchange home and guest teams.
WITH dup AS (
        SELECT team_home AS one
                , team_guest AS two
                , match_date AS match_date
        FROM matches
        UNION ALL
        SELECT team_guest AS one
                , team_home AS two
                , match_date AS match_date
        FROM matches
        )
SELECT m0.*
        , p1.two AS onetwo, p1.match_date AS onedate
        , p2.two AS twotwo, p2.match_date AS twodate
FROM matches m0
        -- all other previous matches for home player
JOIN dup p1 ON p1.one = m0.team_home AND p1.two <> m0.team_guest AND p1.match_date < m0.match_date
        -- all other previous matches for guest player
JOIN dup p2 ON p2.one = m0.team_guest AND p2.two <> m0.team_home AND p2.match_date < m0.match_date AND p1.two = p2.two
WHERE 1=1
        -- suppres older other matches, retaining only the most recent one.
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                FROM dup px
                JOIN dup py ON py.two = px.two
                WHERE px.one = p1.one AND py.one = p2.one
                AND px.match_date < m0.match_date AND (px.match_date > p1.match_date OR px.match_date > p2.match_date)
                AND py.match_date < m0.match_date AND (py.match_date > p2.match_date OR py.match_date > p1.match_date)
                )
ORDER BY
        m0.team_home
        , m0.match_date
        , p1.match_date DESC, p2.match_date DESC
         ;
```